# How to Perform an UPSERT so that I can use both new and old values in update part

Tags: mysql, performance, upsert

Stupid but simple example: assume I have a table `Item` where I keep totals of the items that I receive. There are two columns: `Item_Name` (the primary key), and `Items_In_Stock` with the amount.

When I receive an item A in quantity X:

- If the item does not exist, I insert a new record for Item A, and set the items in stock to X.
- If there exists a record for Item A, where items in stock was Y, then the new value in items in stock is (X + Y).

```
INSERT INTO `item`
(`item_name`, items_in_stock)
VALUES('A', 27)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
`new_items_count` = 27 + (SELECT items_in_stock where item_name = 'A')
```

My problem is that I have multiple columns in my actual table. Is it a good idea to write multiple select statements in the update part?

Of course I can do it in code but is there a better way?

Comment: Why would you use subquery in your example? You could have just used `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE new_items_count = new_items_count + 27`. Seeing you didn't post other columns, it's hard to answer your question because the expected behavior is unknown. What are you doing with other columns? Updating some numbers or?

Comment: Great. Thats answers the question. I didn't know that I can use column name instead of sub query. If you post it as an answer I will accept it as the answer.

Comment: There's a ruby library that defines a MySQL function: https://github.com/seamusabshere/upsert

Comment: what is `new_items_count` here? is it another column on your table?

Answer (score 181, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, you don't have to do the subselect to reference to the row that's causing ON DUPLICATE KEY to fire. So, in your example you can use the following:

```
INSERT INTO `item`
(`item_name`, items_in_stock)
VALUES( 'A', 27)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
`new_items_count` = `new_items_count` + 27
```

Remember that most things are really simple, if you catch yourself overcomplicating something that should be simple then you are most likely doing it the wrong way :)

Comment: **Note:** It looks like the ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE clause will increase the auto-increment value if the PK field is auto-increment, regardless of which effect (INSERT or UPDATE) was triggered (when using InnoDB engine). See: [MySQL Reference Manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

Comment: To prevent code duplication, you should use `new_items_count = new_items_count + VALUES(items_in_stock)`

Comment: Can this be done using `REPLACE` query? It's much more simple that way right

Comment: ^^ "Remember that most things are really simple, if you catch yourself overcomplicating something that should be simple then you are most likely doing it the wrong way "

Answer (score 20):

Although Michael's answer is the right one, you need to know a bit more to do the upsert programmatically:

First, create your table and specify which columns you want a unique index on:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Cell (
  cellId BIGINT UNSIGNED,
  attributeId BIGINT UNSIGNED,
  entityRowId BIGINT UNSIGNED,
  value DECIMAL(25,5),
  UNIQUE KEY `id_ce` (`cellId`,`entityRowId`)
)
```

Then insert some values into it:

```
INSERT INTO Cell VALUES( 1, 6, 199, 1.0 );
```

Try doing the same thing again, and you'll get a duplicate key error, because `cellId` and `entityRowId` are same:

```
INSERT INTO Cell VALUES( 1, 6, 199, 1.0 );
```

> Duplicate entry '1-199' for key 'id_ce'

That's why we use the upsert command:

```
INSERT INTO Cell ( cellId, attributeId, entityRowId, value)
VALUES( 1, 6, 199, 300.0 )
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `value` = `value` + VALUES(`value`)
```

This command takes the value `1.0` that's already there as value and does a `value = value + 300.0`.

So even after executing the above command, there will be only one row in the table, and the value will be `301.0`.

Comment: Shouldn't the final value be `301.0` and not `302.0`?

Comment: This is a good and explanatory answer

Answer (score 13):

**You can get idea from this example:**

Suppose you want to add user wise seven days data

It should have unique value for userid and day like

```
UNIQUE KEY `seven_day` (`userid`,`day`)
```

Here is the table

```
CREATE TABLE `table_name` (
  `userid` char(4) NOT NULL,
  `day` char(3) NOT NULL,
  `open` char(5) NOT NULL,
  `close` char(5) NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `seven_day` (`userid`,`day`)
);
```

And your query will be

```
INSERT INTO table_name (userid,day,open,close) 
    VALUES ('val1', 'val2','val3','val4') 
        ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE open='val3', close='val4';
```

Example:

```
<?php
//If your data is
$data= array(
        'sat'=>array("userid"=>"1001", "open"=>"01.01", "close"=>"11.01"),
        'sun'=>array("userid"=>"1001", "open"=>"02.01", "close"=>"22.01"),
        'sat'=>array("userid"=>"1001", "open"=>"03.01", "close"=>"33.01"),
        'mon'=>array("userid"=>"1002", "open"=>"08.01", "close"=>"08.01"),
        'mon'=>array("userid"=>"1002", "open"=>"07.01", "close"=>"07.01")
    );


//If you query this in a loop
//$conn = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
//mysql_select_db("test", $conn);

foreach($data as $day=>$info) {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO table_name (userid,day,open,close) 
                VALUES ('$info[userid]', '$day','$info[open]','$info[close]') 
            ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE open='$info[open]', close='$info[close]'";
    mysql_query($sql);
}
?>
```

Your data will be in table:

```
+--------+-----+-------+-------+
| userid | day | open  | close |
+--------+-----+-------+-------+
| 1001   | sat | 03.01 | 33.01 |
| 1001   | sun | 02.01 | 22.01 |
| 1002   | mon | 07.01 | 07.01 |
+--------+-----+-------+-------+
```

Comment: Never concatenate data directly into a query.  Use prepared/parameterized queries with PDO or similar.  In the case of this example, it would have been appropriate to at least escape data.

Comment: Note that this code is using the `mysql_*` functions which were removed in PHP 7; when considering a replacement, see [this interesting conundrum](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php#120388) on PDO vs MySQLi.

Answer (score 1):

This is the syntax for an upsert

```
INSERT INTO `{TABLE}` (`{PKCOLUMN}`, `{COLUMN}`) VALUES (:value)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `{COLUMN}` = :value_dup';
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have value for PK Column, or Unique Index on a column which satisfies unicity, You can use `INSERT IGNORE`, `INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE`, or `REPLACE`

**Example with `INSERT IGNORE`**

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO Table1
    (ID, serverID, channelID, channelROLE)
VALUES
    (....);
```

**Example with `INSERT INTO .. ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`**

```
SET @id = 1,
    @serverId = 123545,
    @channelId = 512580,
    @channelRole = 'john';
INSERT INTO Table1
    (ID, serverID, channelID, channelROLE)
VALUES
    (@id, @serverId, @channelId, @channelRole)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    serverId = @serverId,
    channelId = @channelId,
    channelRole = @channelRole;
```

**Example with `Replace`**

```
REPLACE INTO table1
    (ID, serverID, channelID, channelROLE)
VALUES
    (...);
```

Comment: What does it do? Does it ignore the entire row? Or the unique column(s) only? Please expand your answer

Answer (score 0):

Example for upsert

```
INSERT INTO table1 (col1, col2, col3)
VALUES ($1, $2, $3)
ON CONFLICT (col1)
DO
UPDATE
SET col2 = $2, col3 = $3
WHERE col1 = $1
RETURNING col1
```

Comment: This one is for Postgres, not MySQL. :-)