# How to update and insert data in a single SQL Query .

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle10g

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Oracle: how to UPSERT (update or insert into a table?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237327/oracle-how-to-upsert-update-or-insert-into-a-table)
>   [How to Perform an UPSERT so that I can use both new and old values in update part](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6107752/how-to-perform-an-upsert-so-that-i-can-use-both-new-and-old-values-in-update-par)

I want to know that how a single Query can update and delete data from database .

Please help me with this :)

Comment: Do you have a specific example you'd like to work on?

Comment: Update and insert, or update and delete?  Your title and question say two different things.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [MERGE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9016.htm) command.
It lets you do upserts. Since 10g it also contains a `DELETE` clause

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3,...)
VALUES (value1, value2, value3,...); DELETE FROM table_name
WHERE some_column=some_value
```

I think

Answer (score 0):

```sql
delete from table where id = 1
update table set name = 'john' where id = 1
```