# Does mySql have an update/insert combo which inserts if the update fails?

Tags: mysql

I'm not optimistic that this can be done without a stored procedure, but I'm curious if the following is possible.

I want to write a single query insert/update that updates a row if it finds a match and if not inserts into the table with the values it would have been updating.

So... something like

```
updateInsert into  table_a set n = 'foo' where p='bar';
```

in the event that there is no row where p='bar' it would automatically insert into table_a set n = 'foo';

EDIT:
Based on a couple of comments I see that I need to clarify that n is not a PRIMARY KEY and the table actually needs the freedom to have duplicate rows.  I just have a situation where a specific entry needs to be unique... perhaps I'm just mixing metaphors in a bad way and should pull this out into a separate table where this key is unique.

Comment: Reference thread - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361340/how-to-insert-if-not-exists-in-mysql

Comment: Does this help at all?:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6107752/how-to-perform-an-upsert-so-that-i-can-use-both-new-and-old-values-in-update-par

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would enforce this with the table schema - utilize a unique multi-column key on the target table and use `INSERT IGNORE INTO` - it should throw an error on a duplicate key, but the insert will ignore on error.

Comment: right... I considered this, but my problem is that the columns that I'm checking against (in my example n) aren't PRIMARY KEYS... I get the sense that they need to be.  The issue is that the table actually needs to be able to accept duplicate rows, I just want to avoid it in certain circumstances and am finding myself having to perform this two step (if exists update if not insert) procedure.

Comment: You don't have to use primary keys. You can use a multi-column unique key. For instance, in mysql, `ALTER TABLE  `mydb`.`test` ADD UNIQUE  `my_multicolumn_key` (  `uid` ,  `fid` )`

Comment: I see. Thanks. It's not exactly what I'm looking for because as I said, I need to have the ability to have fully duplicate rows in this table (other than their row id).  But this is a terrific approach for  the case where the columns can be combined into unique sets.