# which is more efficent, DELETE and INSERT or INSERT and UPDATE

Tags: mysql, sql-update, sql-insert, sql-delete

i have an eav table structure, special_from, special_to and special_display are not required to be filled

i'm making an sql script that populates these eav attributes for products, how my script works is that the data for these 3 values is processed and stored in a temp table, when i have all the data that's when i need to update the eav attributes

it is possible for a products to have these values so i have 2 apposes

1) `DELETE` the eav values for the products i have listed in my temp table then `INSERT` them
2) `INSERT` the values that have not been assigned then `UPDATE` the ones that have

i'm working with up to 10,000 products, so i'm wondering which is more efficient since i want to minimize the amount of time the query takes

Comment: Sounds like what you really want is an [UPSERT](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6107752/102937).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO
  catalog_product_entity_datetime
  (entity_type_id, store_id, entity_id, attribute_id, value)
VALUES
  (4, 0, PRODUCT_ID_1, ATTRIBUTE_ID_FOR_SPECIAL_TO, SOME_DATE_VALUE),
  (4, 0, PRODUCT_ID_1, ATTRIBUTE_ID_FOR_SPECIAL_FROM, SOME_DATE_VALUE),
  (4, 0, PRODUCT_ID_2, ATTRIBUTE_ID_FOR_SPECIAL_TO, SOME_DATE_VALUE),
  (4, 0, PRODUCT_ID_2, ATTRIBUTE_ID_FOR_SPECIAL_FROM, SOME_DATE_VALUE),
  -- ... and so on
  -- ... and so on
  -- ... and so on
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE value = VALUES(value)
```

And similar for the special display field (whichever datatype that may be.

I assumed magento here, since it is the only thing i ever saw using EAV.

With this 2 queries you would be able to update all affected products at once, thus minimizing the impact on the database (reindexing).
Another way would be to do single queries within a loop within a transaction, to avoid a reindex per entry.

Comment: yep, it's magento, there's nothing else that i have to do weird stuff like this for