# Save date format to database

Tags: vb.net, csv, datagridview

I want to create a program that upload `CSV` file in `DataGridView` then after displaying the `csv` file I want all the data in datagridview to save in my database... The problem is the date format can't display as `yyyy/MM/dd` to database.

Error of this code

```
No default member found for type 'Date'.
```

Code

```
Dim sched_date As String

    Dim agent_name, campaign_name, team_name, schedule As Object
    For i As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1

        agent_name = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value()
        campaign_name = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value()
        team_name = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value()
        sched_date = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(3).Value("yyyy/MM/dd")
        schedule = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(4).Value()



        query = " Select * from tbl_sched WHERE   agent_name = '" + agent_name + "'"
        mysql_connect(True)
        cmd = New MySqlCommand(query, SQLConnection)
        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()

        If reader.Read() Then
            mysql_connect(False)
            query = "update tbl_sched set campaign_name='" + campaign_name + "',team_name='" + team_name + "',sched_date='" + sched_date + "',schedule='" + schedule + "' WHERE agent_name ='" + agent_name + "'"


            mysql_connect(True)
            cmd = New MySqlCommand(query, SQLConnection)
            cmd.Connection = SQLConnection
            cmd.CommandText = query
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()


        Else
            mysql_connect(False)
            query = "insert into tbl_sched (agent_name,campaign_name,team_name,sched_date,schedule) values ('" + agent_name + "','" + campaign_name + "','" + team_name + "','" + sched_date + "','" + schedule + "')"
            mysql_connect(True)
            cmd = New MySqlCommand(query, SQLConnection)
            cmd.Connection = SQLConnection
            cmd.CommandText = query
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

        End If

    Next
    MsgBox("Successfully upload CSV file to Database")
```

Comment: Uhh A big Sql Injection opportunity here

Comment: Sir @Steve what do you mean ? i try to change the structure of date into string the data will insert.

Comment: I need to use Date for my query in mysql.

Comment: It is just a comment, perhaps not related to your problem. Sql Injection happens when you concatenate strings to build sql query [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/how-does-the-sql-injection-from-the-bobby-tables-xkcd-comic-work). By the way, in which line the error happens and what is the exact error message?

Comment: sched_date = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(3).Value("yyyy/MM/dd") ----No default member found for type 'Date'.

Comment: But the Database field named `sched_date` has a datatype of Date or is a string ?

Comment: yes sir  the datatype is Date . if i changed to string the data can save but i need to use Date datatype.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A reworking of your code above could be the following

```
Dim sched_date As DateTime
Dim agent_name, campaign_name, team_name, schedule As String

mysql_connect(True/False) ' I don't know what happens here '

For i As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1

    agent_name = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value.ToString()
    campaign_name = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value.ToString()
    team_name = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value.ToString()
    sched_date = Convert.ToDateTime(DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(3).Value)
    schedule = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(4).Value().ToString()

    query = "update tbl_sched set campaign_name=@cname,team_name=@tname,sched_date=@sdate," + 
             "schedule=@sched WHERE agent_name =@aname"

    cmd = New MySqlCommand(query, SQLConnection)
    cmd.Connection = SQLConnection
    cmd.CommandText = query
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cname",campaign_name)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tname",team_name)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sdate",sched_date)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sched", schedule)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@aname", agent_name)
    Dim rowsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

    ' If the Update doesn't find a record then rowsAffected is zero and we could execute the insertion here
    if rowsAffected = 0 Then
        query = "insert into tbl_sched " + 
                "(agent_name,campaign_name,team_name,sched_date,schedule) " + 
                "values (@aname,@cname,@tname,@sdate,@sched)"
        cmd.CommandText = query
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End If

Next
MsgBox("Successfully upload CSV file to Database")
```

First I have used specific data types for your variables. For the DateTime one I have forced the Value grid field to be converted to a DateTime variable and not to a string.

The second step is to remove the lookup for the `agent_name`. Simply executing the Update will return zero if no record has been found to update and so you could execute the insert (Depending on the number of agent already present this could save a lot of round-trip to the database). You could also look at the syntax `INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE` used in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6107752/how-to-perform-an-upsert-so-that-i-can-use-both-new-and-old-values-in-update-par)

The third part is removing the string concatenation and replace it with a parameterized query. In this way no sql injection possible and the work to correctly format the parameter value for the underlying database table is passed to the framework code that handle the dates, strings and decimals with better knowledge.

A not to forget advantage of this approach is also the more understandable written sql strings.

(I have no idea what are the other database fields datatype, if needed the conversion should be applied also to other not strings columns)

Comment: I tried your  code sir i got this error Object reference not set to an instance of an object. agent_name = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value.ToString()

Comment: This means that the mentioned row/cell has no agent_name value?

Comment: after the data save in database ..i got the error error Object reference not set to an instance of an object