# Update SQL Query with array

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a file that i have inserting data into a mySQL Database i want to insert an UPDATE sql query in the script

i have something like this

```
$cols = "col1, col2, col3, col4)";
list($value1, $value2, $value3, $value4) = $items;
array_push($posted_content, $items);

vals = "";
vals .= "$value1 ,"
vals .= "$value2 ,"
vals .= "$value3 ,"
vals .= "$value4 ,"

$sql = "INSERT INTO table ($cols) VALUES ($vals)";
```

I want to put an If/Else statement if it exist. and will update the record.

I have tried something like this but wont work

```
$sql = "UPDATE table SET ($cols) VALUES ($vals) WHERE col1 =" . $value1;
```

Comment: Similar to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6107752/how-to-perform-an-upsert-so-that-i-can-use-both-new-and-old-values-in-update-par other than that search on upsert or merge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update query in Mysql is

```
'UPDATE [tableName] SET col1='value1', col2='value2' WHERE id = requiredRecord '
```

I guess you need to work on your update query.

Answer (score 0):

change that

```
 $cols = "col1, col2, col3, col4)";
```

to

```
  $cols = " col1, col2, col3, col4 ";
```

and this

```
 vals = "";
 vals .= "$value1 ,"
 vals .= "$value2 ,"
 vals .= "$value3 ,"
 vals .= "$value4 ,"
```

to

```
$vals = "";
$vals .= "$value1 ,";
$vals .= "$value2 ,";
$vals .= "$value3 ," ;
$vals .= "$value4 ,";
```

then use this

```
 $sql = "INSERT INTO table ($cols) VALUES ($vals)
         ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
         SET col1 = ". $value1;
```

Comment: Sorry i just typed up a quick example... made a couple mistakes parto suggested thanks for the input