# MySQL moving data between tables, if exist update

Tags: mysql

I am trying to update one table from another in MYSQL, i did:

```
INSERT INTO new_table (id, last_name, first_name, etc) 
SELECT (id, last_name, first_name, etc) FROM uploaded_tmp
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
```

How do I instruct to update the values with the newer values?

Comment: You use `UPDATE` for updating, and `INSERT` for inserting

Comment: or better "UPSERT", http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6107752/how-to-perform-an-upsert-so-that-i-can-use-both-new-and-old-values-in-update-par

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a nice feature called REPLACE

```
REPLACE INTO new_table (id, last_name, first_name, etc) 
SELECT (id, last_name, first_name, etc) FROM uploaded_tmp
```

It behaves just like INSERT, but if duplicate key happens (either PRIMARY or UNIQUE), the old record will be deleted and replaced with new values.

Interested? Read more on http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replace.html

Comment: That's wrong. It is ALWAYS an insert. The old dataset will be deleted and a new one inserted. So if you use `AUTO_INCREMENT` on your `PRIMARY`, there will be a new incremented ID.

Comment: As long as even the primary key is being replaced, it will be the same. If the primary key is not included within replacing data, yes, it will get new index, I should update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

you are missing an **update** statement here.complete it with setting of some data

use :

```
INSERT INTO table(value)
SELECT id, uid
FROM tmp t WHERE uid=x
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ut=uy,yt=iu.....
```

reference :[Mysql site](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

Answer (score 1):

1. Are the IDs of `new_table` and `uploaded_tmp` the same? If not, remove them from the INSERT statement
2. Do you need the ID to be the same after the update? If not see the answer of David162795.
3. If you don't want your `PRIMARY` ID to change you have to use `INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`. But then we must know your `UNIQUE` indices

In this example there is a `PRIMARY` key (`ID`) and a `UNIQUE` index (`last_name`, `first_name`)

```
INSERT INTO new_table (
    last_name,
    first_name,
    val1,
    val2,
    ...
) 
SELECT
    last_name,
    first_name,
    val1,
    val2,
FROM uploaded_tmp
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    val1 = VALUES(val1),
    val2 = VALUES(val2)
```