# Is it possible to update only a single field with ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE in a table with multiple fields?

Tags: mysql, sql, duplicates

Is it possible to update only a single field with ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE in a table with multiple fields?

If I have a table with three fields; key, cats, dogs where key is the primary key is it possible to update a record on duplicate key, changing only one field, (for my example `cats`) without changing the value in the other non-key fields (`dogs`). This is without knowing what the value of `dogs` from outside of the database at the time of insertion (i.e. I have a variable holding cats value, but not one holding dogs value)

```
INSERT INTO `myTable` (`key`,`cats`) VALUES('someKey1','Manx') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `cats` = 'Manx';
```

At the moment when I run something like this and the key already exists in the table `dogs` is set to NULL even when it had a value previously.

Comment: The behavior you describe is not correct.  Only the columns in the `update` clause should be affected by this query.

Comment: Hi Gordon, spot on thank you - you made me test my own example rather than production code and you are right. Back to the drawing board on my issue. Thank you for the feedback

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gordon is right, it does not work the way I described. If you see this, it is not caused by the ON DUPLICATE UPDATE statement, but something else. Here is the proof:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `myTable` (
  `key` varchar(20) NOT NULL default '',
  `cats` varchar(20) default NULL,
  `dogs` varchar(20) default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`key`)
)
```

The run

```
INSERT INTO `myTable` (`key`, `cats`, `dogs`) VALUES
('someKey1', NULL, 'jack-russell');
```

Then run

```
INSERT INTO `myTable` (`key`,`cats`) VALUES
('someKey1','Manx') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `cats` = 'manx';
```

Then check the table

Answer (score 1):

I think you should try to UPSERT.

Please examine this:

```
INSERT INTO `item` (`item_name`, items_in_stock) VALUES( 'A', 27)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `new_items_count` = `new_items_count` + 27
```

[MySQL UPSERT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6107752/how-to-perform-an-upsert-so-that-i-can-use-both-new-and-old-values-in-update-par)