# MySQL CASE For Registration

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I register user via `Facebook Login Authentication` and works well.

I store `facebook_id`, `facebook_email` and `facebook_birthday`.
Here is the query that I would like to run;

**Case 1:** If this user has facebook_id which exist in MySQL, update facebook_email and facebook_birthday *(in case of they change)*

**Case 2:** If this user's facebook_id is not exist in MySQL, insert into facebook_id, facebook_email and facebook_birthday

I tried this but didn't happen. Thanks in advance.

```
SELECT facebook_id
CASE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM user_facebook WHERE facebook_id = 123123123)
    WHEN 0 THEN INSERT INTO user_facebook (facebook_id) VALUES (1233)
    WHEN 1 THEN UPDATE user_facebook SET facebook_email = "123@gmail.com"
    ELSE
END
FROM user_facebook
```

Comment: SELECT's, and queries in general, cannot be used like procedural code. (i.e. a SELECT cannot execute an UPDATE or INSERT).

Comment: Upsert might help in your case. Check this out- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6107752/how-to-perform-an-upsert-so-that-i-can-use-both-new-and-old-values-in-update-par

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for an INSERT statement with the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The operation you are asking about is called a ["merge"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_(SQL)) or "upsert".

Assuming `facebook_id` is the primary key, or at least has a unique index, you can add the optional [`ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) clause to an `INSERT` statement.

```
INSERT INTO user_facebook
    (facebook_id, facebook_email, facebook_birthday)
    VALUES (123123123, '123@gmail.com', '1998-05-02')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    facebook_email = VALUES(facebook_email)
    facebook_birthday = VALUES(facebook_birthday)
```

If the `facebook_id` already exists in the table, the email and birthday will be updated for that record. If not, a new record will be inserted.

Comment: `INSERT INTO user_facebook (facebook_id, facebook_email, facebook_name, facebook_birthday, facebook_username)
    VALUES('123123123','mymail@gmail.com','John John','05/11/1998','johnjohn')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE


    facebook_email = VALUES(facebook_email),
    facebook_name = VALUES(facebook_name),
    facebook_birthday = VALUES(facebook_birthday),
    facebook_username = VALUES(facebook_username)`

Thanks for answer. I did it like this but it insert the user even though facebook_id is exist in SQL. Where I'm wrong at?

Comment: It sounds like you need to add a unique index on `facebook_id`. In order for the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` part to be activated, there has to be a duplicate key. If there isn't, it will just insert as usual, so there has to be something there to indicate that it's a duplicate. That can either be a unique index or a primary key (which is unique by definition).

Comment: Before to try that SQL Query, I had a user with '123123123' ID.
Except for facebook_id, I have id value which is AUTO_INCREMENT. Is might be something wrong with that? I must use that in query?

Comment: No, that auto_increment id value is fine, but it isn't going to be useful in this scenario. I'm not saying you should remove it; it could still be useful in general, but the thing that needs to be unique for what you're trying to do here is the facebook_id.

Comment: It worked, thank you very much! I confused about primary and unique. After I made facebook_id unique, it worked. I missed. Thanks again it saved me.