# Checking for existence PHP

Tags: php

I'm trying to check for the existence of certain data in the database before performing a function, my code looks like this at the moment. I can't seem to figure this out.

Comment: what is not working?

Comment: this part is wrong: `...$menuitemcode& reservering=$re...` for a starter. But we don't know what your problem is...

Comment: _"as soon as I get home"_ doesn't sound like you are prepared to co-work in solving your unknown problem...

Comment: @TorbjörnStabo I don't think the space after `&` will get parsed correctly. either the value is in `$_GET['%20reserving']` or there's no param at all. No, I didn't test it, just an assumption

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option you might want to be aware of is an "upsert": Insert a new row (of the column doesn't exist); otherwise, update the existing row:

- [How to Perform an UPSERT so that I can use both new and old values in update part](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6107752/)
- [How to INSERT If Row Does Not Exist (UPSERT) in MySQL](https://chartio.com/resources/tutorials/how-to-insert-if-row-does-not-exist-upsert-in-mysql/)

EXAMPLE:

```
SET @id = 1,
    @title = 'In Search of Lost Time',
    @author = 'Marcel Proust',
    @year_published = 1913;
INSERT INTO books
    (id, title, author, year_published)
VALUES
    (@id, @title, @author, @year_published)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    title = @title,
    author = @author,
    year_published = @year_published;
```

Another caveat, since you're updating your database with respect to a PHP (possibly internet-facing) app: *ALWAYS* use a prepared statement (as opposed to a raw SQL "insert" or "update"):

- [PHP - Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

This will help mitigate SQL injection attacks.