# Running separate queries based on results of conditional

Tags: php, mysql

Essentially I would like create a query that checks if the posted code already exists, if the code value already exists in the Table1 run the following update query:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare('UPDATE Table1
    SET value = 2
    WHERE code = :codeNumber');
$stmt->execute([
    'codeNumber' => $_POST['code']
]);
```

If the code value does not exist run the following query:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare( ' INSERT INTO `Table1` (`code`,`value`)
    VALUES (:code, :value) ' );
$stmt->execute([
    'code' => $_POST['code'],
    'value' => $_POST['value']
]);
```

How can something like this be done?

Comment: Sounds like you want to look up `INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` syntax.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6107752/how-to-perform-an-upsert-so-that-i-can-use-both-new-and-old-values-in-update-par

Comment: Using Duplicate Key method would assume that my code column contains a key?