# R Multiple queries via RODBC in MySQL

Tags: mysql, r, rodbc

I want to do a lot of updates in one query in MySQL:

```
require(RODBC)

q <- "UPDATE myTable SET NumberOfSignals=4 WHERE ItemID=1361; "
q <- paste(q,"UPDATE myTable NumberOfSignals=5 WHERE ItemID=1362; ")
q <- paste(q,"UPDATE myTable NumberOfSignals=6 WHERE ItemID=1363; ")

res <- sqlQuery(con, q, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

In mySQL I got an error message:

```
MySQL][ODBC 8.3(w) Driver][mysqld-8.0.20]You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UPDATE...
```

It happens because of multi-query limitation in MySQL. I have tried to use `multiResults=TRUE` in `sqlQuery` but I have a message the argument is not used.

**I know** that I can do a loop and update one by one, but for performance reasons I would like to avoid it. There could be a few thousands of updates in one query.

Is there a way to change MySQL configuration, this database schema or just the query alone and make multi-queries working?

Comment: FYI, _"few thousands of updates"* sounds like you would benefit from doing an `UPSERT` instead of 1000s of individual updates. Assuming you have a `data.frame` with `NumberOfSignals` and `ItemID`, the steps: (1) insert that 2-column frame into a temporary table; (2) perform an UPSERT, using https://stackoverflow.com/q/6107752/3358272 as a template; (3) remove the temp table. Assuming the indexes of your target table are decent, this should be _far faster_ than updating individual lines.

Comment: If you go with an upsert (IODKU), I recommend batches of 100.